# Packaging java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one java project with two class. One of them is with main method. I also have two files one of them is a.properties and second one i b.xls. The way I want to export this project is in one executable jar but withour these two files(a.properties and b.xls) being compressed inside this executable jar. The reason for this is, user who run this project should able to change the properties file(a.properties) and also excel file(b.xls). I also want to include the libraries I have used for this project.

I am using Eclipse helios and jdk 1.6.

I really appreciate if somebody will provide me the steps for this. I already tried the Export option with executable jar but it compress everything including two files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging is usually done by an ANT script. Inside of Eclipse you can simplify such a scribt by using the compiled class files generated by Eclipse:

Save the following file as build.xml, adapt your filenames and run it as Ant Build. 
It will a file named package.zip which includes the created jar and (outside of the jar) your two additional files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="pack">
    <target name="pack">
        <jar destfile="myprog.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.example.myapp.Main" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="bin" defaultexcludes="true">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
        <zip destfile="package.zip">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="myprog.jar" />
                <include name="myprog.properties" />
                <include name="myprog.xls" />
            </fileset>
        </zip>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks like this build file is missing something. Somehow it is not including class files, two properties file and reference libraries. I modified this file based on my projects.

Comment: I find the problem. Include tag should be like this <include name="**/*.class"/> and to copy referenced jar I provide the compete path. But this was really a quick answer to start working on. Thanks a lot for your time, really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to exclude the files from the jar

```
<jar jarfile="some.jar" excludes="some.properties,some.properties">
        <fileset dir="${build}" />
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="some.class"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

1> Keep the 2 files(a.properties and b.xls file in root directory)
2> Keep only the the src file in \src folder
3> compile the src file .java to .class file
4> the respective .class file appears in \classes folder
5> run the jar command on classes folder only
usage  jar -cvf *.class example.jar
6>you get the desired jar file which contains only the .class file.

Hope my solution works out
Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

With eclipse you can simply go to the project explorer.  Right click the project name and select export.  Under Java, click runnable jar file (or just jar file if that is what you want).  Follow the prompts and you are done.